# How to access member enum's of other classes (c++)

Tags: c++, class, enums, nested

I need to access a public enum belonging to another class, to simplify, something like this:

```
class obj
{
public:

    enum Type
    {
        t1,
        t2,
        t3
    };

    Type type;
};

class otherObj
{
public:

    void setType(obj* o);

};

void otherObj::setType(obj* o)
{
    o->type = obj::Type::t1;
    return;
}
```

How do I do that, because the line

```
o->type = obj::Type::t1;
```

throws out an error:

```
obj::Type is not a class or namespace.
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj::t1
obj::t2
obj::t3
```

Aren't C++ enums great? The values fall into the scope above them even though the enum can be treated as a type.

Answer (score 0):

You either just use

```
obj::t1;
```

or specify the [`class` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) with your `enum` declaration

```
enum class Type {
    t1,
    t2,
    t3
};
```

Comment: Actually adding the class attribute didn't fix it. It shows me a warning that I am using C++11 feature, but still doesn't work. Maybe I need to change my compiler settings somewhere?

Comment: @V0ldek _"It shows me a warning that I am using C++11 feature"_ You switch on `--std=c++11`  to fix this, it's the current standard. May be you should look for a more recent c++ compiler, that runs in this mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03, the enum values belong to the enclosing scope. Hence, replacing `obj::Type::t1` with `obj::t1` would work for you.

This is somewhat counter-intuitive, and is addressed by the `enum class` feature in C++11, which puts the enum values directly in the enum scope. Thus, if you use `enum class` in a C++11 compliant compiler, then you would be able to use `obj::Type::t1` as you are currently doing.